# implement HTML tags inside JSP method

Tags: html, jsp

I have created a method in jsp. and inside that method i have used some html tags using out.println(); method but it will give u out cannot resolved.

here is my code:

```
<%! public int display(int start){

        int limit;
        limit = DEFAULT >= testList.size() ? testList.size() : DEFAULT;
        System.out.println("size : "+ testList.size());
        System.out.println("limit : "+ limit);
            for(int count = start; count < limit; count++){
        TestDetail detailContain = (TestDetail)testList.get(count); 
        tcName = detailContain.getTestName();
        System.out.println("id : "+ tcName);
        tcSource = detailContain.getSource();
        tcDescription = detailContain.getDrescription();
        idVal = detailContain.getID();
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td width = '5%'><input id='"+idVal+"' type = 'checkbox' name = 'Tests' value = '"+tcName+"'/></td>");
        out.println("<td width = '20%'><a href = './"+tcSource+"'>"+tcName+"</a></td>");
        out.println("<td width = '75%'>"+tcDescription+"</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        }
         return limit;
    }
            %>
```

it gives this error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 108 in the jsp file: /Xyz/def/abc.jsp
out cannot be resolved

Comment: @HardikMishra i m implementing paging concept for that i have created this method and to display next page contain i use to call same function through button.i m using eclipse to development in the editor it just give out can not resolve

Comment: Its bad solution though. In JSP pages the implicit objects are created automatically for you within the service method only. Whatever code you write in <%!.. %> part goes out side service().So, It won't be accessible.

Comment: @HardikMishra pls give me some hint because i am totally new in JSP

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are writing "out.println" inside a java method.
When you use a declaration tag to define your own method it does not have access to the "service" method where all the JSP code goes.You can pass an Object output stream as parameter to your method as follows and then make use of out.println

```
public int display(int start,**OutputStream outObject**)

        outObject.println("<tr>");
        outObject.println("<td width = '5%'><input id='"+idVal+"' type = 'checkbox' name = 'Tests' value = '"+tcName+"'/></td>");
        outObject.println("<td width = '20%'><a href = './"+tcSource+"'>"+tcName+"</a></td>");
        outObject.println("<td width = '75%'>"+tcDescription+"</td>");
        outObject.println("</tr>");
```

Comment: there is no such method println in OutputStream class